# How to map a vector of values between 0 and 1 to a colorful bar in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors, p-value

I want to map a vector of p values to a colorful bar. Since they are p values, I am extremely interested in those that are less than 0.05 or 0.1. So, I hope the color should be darker for smaller values, and be lighter for larger values.

I tried the following code:

```
COL = c(0.01,0.02,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.8)
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,length(COL)), ylim=c(0,1), xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
# rect(0:(length(COL)-1), 0, 1:length(COL), 1, col=COL) 
rect(0:(length(COL)-1), 0, 1:length(COL), 1, col=10-10*COL)
```

I got a colorful bar, which is imperfect in the sense that they are too colorful. I hope they could fall into the same color series. I don't mind taking a log transform or any other kind of transform to my vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get more continuous changes might be to make everything one color but with different intensities, depending on your vector. For example,  here are a bunch of different blues.

```
COL2 = rgb(0.1+COL*0.3, 0.1+COL*0.3, COL*0.8+0.2)
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,length(COL)), ylim=c(0,1), xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
rect(0:(length(COL)-1), 0, 1:length(COL), 1, col=COL2)
```

[image: Blue bars with different intensities]